# Firestore get the latest document

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I wanna compare and find the latest date among all the chat documents. Then get the message and date field from the latest one and display it. May I know is there a way to do this?

[image: firestore chat]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for a [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) that is [ordered by descending `date`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) and then [limiting it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data) to one result.

So something like:

```
Query query = collectionRef.orderBy("date", Direction.DESCENDING).limit(1);
```

Then you can just [read the data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) or [attach a listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) to also get updates.